# Custom SplitViewController with two UINavigationViewControllers Status Bar issue

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, uinavigationbar

I have a custom SplitViewController which contains two UINavigationViewControllers. They are aligned like this:

```
 Portrait          Landscape
__________       _____________
|        |      | C |         |
| NavCo1 |      | o | NavCo2  |
|________|      | 1 |         |
|        |      |___|_________|
| NavCo2 |      
|________|
```

The problem on iOS 7  UINavigationBar for NavCo2 doesn't cover the status bar which you see in the second screenshot:

[image]
[image]

I looked at the frame of both UINavigationBar and the seem the same. I use topLayoutGuide to align them and couldn't find any difference in the two navigation controllers or the view controllers they contain.

**Edit:**

Looking more into it, it seems that `UINavigationBar.barPosition` is set to `UIBarPositionTopAttached`. The problem is this is set over the `UIBarPositioningDelegate` which can't be changed on UINavigationViewControllers: *"Cannot manually set the delegate on a UINavigationBar managed by a controller."*

Comment: Have you tried MGSplitViewController https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController

Comment: @BilalSaifudeen haven't tried MGSplitViewController but based on my finding I don't think it would help with this issue.